# How to combine this arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine the three arrays shown below and I don't know how to do that, I want to take the `companyCode` of each array and make it for one array.

I have an array like this,

```
Array(
   [0] => Array(
             [companyCode] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => 'AD'
                     )
             [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => 'NYCT01'
                     )
             [vehicleRentalPrefType] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => 'ECAR'
                     )
             [rateAmount] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => '295.62'
                     )
         );
   [1] => Array(
             [companyCode] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => 'AD'
                     )
             [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => 'NYCT01'
                     )
             [vehicleRentalPrefType] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => 'SCAR'
                     )
             [rateAmount] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => '356.25'
                     )
   [2] => Array(
             [companyCode] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => 'AD'
                     )
             [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => 'NYCT01'
                     )
             [vehicleRentalPrefType] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => 'PCAR'
                     )
             [rateAmount] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
                            [0] => '562.36'
                     )
          )
)
```

I want this:

```
Array(
    [AD] => Array(
              [NYCT01] => Array(
                        [ECAR] => Array(
                                  [0] => '295.62'
                          )
                        [SCAR] => Array(
                                  [0] => '356.25'
                          )
                        [PCAR] => Array(
                                  [0] => '562.36'
                          )
                 )
        )
)
```

How can I do that, I tried to do some loops but I'm getting no result please help.

Comment: I don't believe there is a function like that in the default build, so you need to write your own.

Comment: I just submitted a loop what I tried to do, but I don't know if you'll understand what I'm doing there, please take a look.

Comment: I don't know why you guys are down voting him like crazy. He posted what he tried, he just doesn't know how to go about it any further. You could just give him a hint and a link to some functions instead of down voting him into never coming back here for help.

Comment: In the future, you really need to post the _code_ that you tried, not just the array you are working with and the desired output.

Comment: I think you're not right, the answer of the question can be useful for other users as well in the future, I think you're going wrong.

Comment: @saad (cc thegrede) This is not a good question. Basically, he's asking us to write a function for him. SO is _not a quick help forum_. Questions should get answers that help one _learn_, and should be useful to future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function I created to group arrays a couple of days ago:

**for PHP 5.3 and above**

```
class Fx
{
    public static function GroupBy(&$arr, $groupby, $valueFunctions = null)
    {
        $groupby = is_array($groupby) ? $groupby : array($groupby);
        $valueFunctions = is_array($valueFunctions) ? $valueFunctions : array($valueFunctions);

        $group1 = array();
        foreach($arr as $elem)
        {
            $group = is_callable($groupby[0]) ? $groupby[0]($elem) : $elem[$groupby[0]];
            $group1[$group][] = is_callable($valueFunctions[0]) ? $valueFunctions[0]($elem) : (is_null($valueFunctions[0]) ? $elem : $elem[$valueFunctions[0]]);
        }

        if(count($groupby) > 1)
        {
            $group2 = array();
            $gb_next = array_slice($groupby, 1);
            $vf_next = (count($valueFunctions) > 1) ? array_slice($valueFunctions, 1) : null;
            foreach($group1 as $group => $elems)
            {
                $group2[$group] = self::GroupBy($elems, $gb_next, $vf_next);
            }

            return $group2;
        }

        return $group1;
    }
}
```

**>=5.3 example**

```
$new = Fx::GroupBy(
    $arr, 
    array(
        function($elem){ return (string)$elem['companyCode'][0]; },
        function($elem){ return (string)$elem['name'][0]; },
        function($elem){ return (string)$elem['vehicleRentalPrefType'][0]; }
    ),
    array(
        null,
        null,
        function($elem){ return (float)$elem['rateAmount'][0]; }
    )
);

print_r($new);
```

**for PHP 5.2 and possibly under**

```
class Fx
{
    public static function GroupBy(&$arr, $groupby, $valueFunctions = null)
    {
        $groupby = is_array($groupby) ? $groupby : array($groupby);
        $valueFunctions = is_array($valueFunctions) ? $valueFunctions : array($valueFunctions);

        $group1 = array();
        foreach($arr as $elem)
        {
            $gbIsFunc = (substr($groupby[0], 0, 5) == 'func:');
            $gbFunc = substr($groupby[0], 5);

            $vIsFunc = (substr($valueFunctions[0], 0, 5) == 'func:');
            $vFunc = substr($valueFunctions[0], 5);

            $group = $gbIsFunc ? $gbFunc($elem) : $elem[$groupby[0]];
            $group1[$group][] = $vIsFunc ? $vFunc($elem) : (is_null($valueFunctions[0]) ? $elem : $elem[$valueFunctions[0]]);
        }
        if(count($groupby) > 1)
        {
            $group2 = array();
            $gb_next = array_slice($groupby, 1);
            $vf_next = (count($valueFunctions) > 1) ? array_slice($valueFunctions, 1) : null;
            foreach($group1 as $group => $elems)
            {
                $group2[$group] = self::GroupBy($elems, $gb_next, $vf_next);
            }

            return $group2;
        }

        return $group1;
    }
}
```

**<=5.2 example**

```
function gbFunc1($elem){ return (string)$elem['companyCode'][0]; }
function gbFunc2($elem){ return (string)$elem['name'][0]; }
function gbFunc3($elem){ return (string)$elem['vehicleRentalPrefType'][0]; }
function vFunc3($elem){ return (float)$elem['rateAmount'][0]; }

$new = Fx::GroupBy($arr, array('func:gbFunc1', 'func:gbFunc2', 'func:gbFunc3'), array(null, null, 'func:vFunc3'));

print_r($new);
```

Comment: Np :) let me know if you need help making it work.

Comment: I need to change something in the class, or just in the output, to make it work with xml objects?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change anything in the class, just what you pass to the function. If you can send me the php code for your xml object I can show you how to do it.

Comment: Umm nvm, I managed to recreate it, give me a few minutes. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @thegrede Hey, there you go, I edited my answer at the bottom. It should do what you want, just replace the first parameter with your array.

Comment: Do I miss something here `function($elem){ return (string)$elem['companyCode'][0]; },`, I'm getting an error `unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'` on that line

Comment: Oh man, you're using an older version of php5 than me. You need php 5.3 for my code to work :( Which version are you on?

Comment: I'm using version 5.2.17

Comment: @thegrede There, made a version to work with 5.2. It requires a bit mode writing, but works :)

Comment: Wow genius, exactly what I want to, thanks a million. :)